# NoSQL as a data mining solution?

Tags: data-mining, olap, data-analysis, star-schema, nosql

In what ways are NoSQL databases be more useful in data mining than say OLAP databases or how is it less useful?

Is there an advantage in having a fast data-retrieval from gigantic volume of data but also having a schema-less database?

Answer (score 3):

### It's about the advanced query capabilities

And **NoSQL databases are rather useless** usually here.

They are designed for **extremely primitive queries** such as key-value storing.

But you can't do much analysis with that.

A database suitable for data mining would need to allow:

- finding similar records (k nearest neighbors) with domain-specific similarity functions
- nearest-neighbor self-joins, radius-self-joins
- pairwise comparisons
- optimization of mathematical equations and fast vector math, preferrably, with GPU offloading

As is, what people do when mining databases is ETL:

- extract what they need via `SELECT`
- transform it into the desired scheme
- load it from the database into the data mining application

i.e. the database does ETL, but the data mining happens *outside*.